# Headphones what am I missing and how much do I need it

Tags: headphones

So I recently miss placed my traveling headphones. I know silly me.

So instead of buying then again, I've decided to upgrade, what sort of headphones are everyone using for portable situations?

Casual listening?

Looking super fly on the street telling people you do audio, followed by blank expressions?

Thanks
C

Answer (score 3):

1. Sennheiser HD650's
2. Ultimate Ears In-Ear Reference Monitors
3. What you should totally wear on the street.

[image]

Comment: Utopia's Ultrasones are definitely a good buy.

Comment: I hope there is a warranty on the little bat on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

From similar questions on here I purchased Ultrasones. They are actually pretty awesome and I really enjoy casual listening on them as well as side-checking my mixes and recordings on the road.

Comment: I need a pair of these to replace my old ATH-M20's

Comment: @Utopia Are these the ones you have? http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/547240-REG/Ultrasone_HFI_780_HFI_780_Closed_Back_Stereo_Headphones.html

Comment: @C3SSound I think they are one step below - let me find them for you. I got them on sale at Amazon for $70

Comment: Here they are http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/557125-REG/Ultrasone_HFI_450_HFI_450_Closed_Back_Stereo_Hi_Fi.html

Answer (score 0):

I like the Sennheiser HD280 Pros.  I still prefer monitors over headphones in general, but these are nice phones that have a great price point (a place like Sam Ash or West LA Music will usually sell em for about $80-$90) and structural integrity akin to that of the MDR7506 (if not more durable), but the sound quality and outside noise cancellation is leaps and bounds better than the Sony cans in my experience.  I guess what I like about them is they're like decently high-quality yet of acceptable disposable nature thanks to their low cost.

Comment: I have the Sony HD280 Pros's and I find that the frequency response is strangely dark.  The one reason that I do like them more than other headphones of similar price is that they have a decent isolation which you can't find from the Sony cans even though their frequency response is more pleasing to my ear.

Comment: Interesting to hear the difference of preference ;).  They're the Sennheiser HD280s in case there was confusion there.  I find it interesting because I personally find the MDR7506 far too bright and Upper-Mid to my ears yet the HD280s sound decently flat, like the 7506 are missing the 120-200kHz range but the 2-4kHz range is +6 from flat.  The BD990s though sound dull to my ears event though those are "advertised" as being perfectly flat.  Not bad either way, just an interesting observation ;) 